# Extract variable definitions and variable reference from a 'C' program

Tags: c++, c, parsing, shell

I've been assigned a strange project at college. I've been asked to extract variable definitions and references from a given input 'C' program.

Each line in the input program contains respective line number at the beginning and followed by a space, and then the actual code begins.

Consider the following program..

```
1 int main()  
2 {  
3 int a,b,c;  
4 printf("Enter the values of a and b\n");  
5 scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);  
6 c=a+b;  
7 printf("The sum of two numbers is %d",c);  
8 }
```

And the input for the program which I'm developing is a 'C' program, in which single line consists of a single statement..
ie, we know that a whole program can be written in a single line. But not in my case, that is once there is a termination(semicolon), the lines following the semi colon is shifted to next line..

Anyways my job is to extract the variable definitions/declarations and variable use/reference in the given input C program..

Consider the above program, 
In line number 3, variables a,b and c are declared, hence it has to be printed under the "definition" column of the output..

Similarly in the statement 5, values of a and b are being initialized using a scanf statement, hence variables a and b should be printed under the definition column of the output..

Now consider the statement 6, The value of variable c is being initialized/defined hence c must be printed under the definition column.. At the same time, values of a and b are being used to determine the value of c, hence variables a and b must be printed under the "reference" column of the output..

And lastly, the value of variable c is being referenced/used in the statement 7, hence the variable c has to be printed under the referenced column..

The sample output of the program is as shown below..

```
Line Number          Defined Variable        Referenced Variable
_____________________________________________________________________
  1                       --                           --
  2                       --                           --
  3                     a,b,c                         --
  4                       --                           --
  5                      a,b                          --
  6                       c                           a,b
  7                       --                          c
  8                       --                          --
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem????
Remember, I need to write a C/C++ program or even shell script is allowed for the project..
I need to consider the mathematical expressions, logical expressions, built in function calls, user defined function calls and function definitions as well..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is for what kind of class?  And the purpose of this exercise is?

Comment: @ab07: "These sort of things happen in our universities". You ought to ask "What do you (the prof) expect me to learn form this assignment"? If he expects you to do this with anything other than a real parser, I'd wonder what he expected, and whether there was much point to this.  5f he expects you do it with a parser, and you don't know parsing, you're in trouble. If he expects you to do with a real parser, I don't understand the point of the numbers in left margin; are you sure that is part of the requirements?

Comment: This is horribly imprecise. What do you do with `if`? Will you spread the if-statement across multiple lines? Will it not then violate the rule "in which single line consists of a single statement"? Do you keep it on the same line, and then have multiple statements nested in a nested compound statement? Thereby having multiple scalar statements in the same line?

Comment: @Ira.. Ya he expects me to extract out the definitions and references from the given 'C' program.. We all know what the data flow graph is.. In it, each node is assigned a definition as well as references.. Each node in the data flow graph represents a statement in a C program.. So definitely it has got to do something with the parsing.. Yes a real parser.. And yes numbers are very much important.. So have to do explore the things..  I'm a computer science student.. An intermediate..

Comment: @Johannes No! how can we spread the 'if' statement across multiple lines!?!    if(condition)   in a single statement..

Answer (score 1):

The standard thing to do would be to write a tokenizer and a parser to partially compile your input program.  Then you'll know what expressions are on each line.  For the purpose of this assignment, you can just match regular expressions up to:

1. variable definition
2. variable reference

and spit out the captures for each line.  So for example the variable reference might be something like "a valid C identifier anywhere besides after a valid C datatype".  The captures here would be "a valid C identifier", so just print those out under the "Referenced Variable" column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But how can I start?? Should I use C programming?? Any tutorials for "Tokenizer and a parser"?? Can you guide me please? :)

Comment: @abk07, if this is **your** assignment, I'd assume you have been taught the basics of parser theory in school/uni. If this is not the case, I find it strange you'd get an assignment like this. Anyway, Milimetric gave you some decent hints of what is needed to do this. I suggest you do some research on your own (open a book, search the Net, whatever) before posting follow up questions. SO is a great place to get specific questions answered, not to hold ones hand to guide them through an entire assignment, IMO. This is what your teacher or the TA of your class are good at. Best of luck.

Comment: @Milimetric:  The notion of "definees" and "references" in a real C program is trickier than this.  If  you call foo(&x), x might be "defined" in the sense of getting a value. Or not, depending on what's in foo.  Similarly for "referenced".  To do this *right*, you need a full points-to analysis...

Comment: @Ira - I'm not following.  A variable definition is pretty standard in most typed languages: int x ...  @abk07 - hunt around for places like the C language specification to get ideas for regular expressions: http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/c_html/c.html#m16

Comment: @MMillimetric: Don't mix up "declaration", "definition" and "access" (reference).  The example give by OP does mix these; he has lines 3 and 5 as "definitions".

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to start with a full-blown C parser.  You could write this yourself, but you're probably better off using something pre-existing, such as [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/).